# How to only show output if grep returns nothing in while loop

Tags: bash, loops, curl, grep, conditional-statements

I have a file that contains a list of domains. I am looping over this list to use curl and grep a particular element. It does as intended, however, I am needing the **opposite** of that; meaning, I am needing to only see output if it **doesn't** find my search string.

So if the file is:

```
https://www.somewebsite1 dot com
https://www.somewebsite2 dot com
https://www.somewebsite3 dot com
```

My bash is:

```
while read n;
do
echo $n;
curl -s $n | grep 'class="my_class"';
done < /my/file/location.txt
```

The output is:

```
https://www.somewebsite1 dot com
                    <p class="my_class">"some_value"</p>
https://www.somewebsite2 dot com <--- NEED ONLY THESE LINES
https://www.somewebsite3 dot com
                    <p class="my_class">"some_value"</p>
```

I only want the 2nd domain that did not have any output for grep. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Even if it might be possible to provide a one-liner, I like to show in a more structured example how to achieve the goal.

```
#!/bin/bash

SEARCHPATTERN=$1

while read URL; # from list of URLs
do

  # echo "Going to gather CONTENT of ${URL}"
  CONTENT=$(curl --silent https://${URL} --write-out " %{http_code}")
  # echo "Gathered CONTENT is\n\n${CONTENT}"

  # Check if provided search pattern is part of the content
  if grep -q ${SEARCHPATTERN} <<< ${CONTENT}; then
    echo "Found ${SEARCHPATTERN} in ${URL}"
  else
    echo "Did NOT found ${SEARCHPATTERN} in ${URL}"
  fi

done < URLs.lst
```

You may also take advantage from [Can grep return true/false?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48535/) and [How to grep on a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163810/).